# Calling latex from vim stopped working

Tags: text-processing, vim, latex

When I try to compile my latex document from within `vim` by issuing: `:w|!lualatex %` (leaving out the `w` command does not solve the problem) it compiles but it does not save any files. If I call `lualatex` directly from the command line `lualatex FILE.tex` it compiles and saves the files as expected.

The behaviour is especially strange since I never had this problem before. So basically I cannot point to what the problem may be. I'm on an `archlinux` box.

Does anyone have any suggestion how to solve this problem or at least has some ideas what tests might allow me to find possible causes?

Comment: is your vim instance in the same directory as the tex file? I'd assume you started it somewhere else and the results/artifacts of the latex compilation are placed inside this directory...

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the case. I have checked that. Furthermore, my `.vimrc` contains the lines `cmap cwd lcd %:p:h` and `cmap cd. lcd %:p:h` which automatically switch the working directory to that of the current file.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that `lualatex` received an update that causes the problem. Which would make it a `latex` related question and should probably go on Stackoverflow. But I thought I’d check with other `vim` enthusiasts.

Comment: I revoke my previous command and assert the exact opposite: It is exactly as you said @Ulrich Dangel. Despite this never happening before and my `.vimrc` setup vim did indeed compile in the wrong directory. Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it is very likely that the current working directory for vim or for your `lualatex` process is **not** the directory you were looking at, as:

- If you run `lualatex` directly it works as expected
- You don't get any error when running `lualatex` from vim

That indicates that:

1. `lualatex` works in general
2. there must be a difference between when you run it from vim and directly from your terminal

Two typically differences are either environment variables or the current working directory if you launch a process from within another one. As there seem to  no errors/issues related to environment variables (e.g. `PATH`) it is very likely that your current working directory in that vim instance is different to the directory you looked for your ouptut.

Comment: I reran `lcd %:p:h` one single time from vim and everything works as expected again. I can close vim and open it again and it will switch working directories as expected. Strange... Sorry about the fuss.